# What is correct plot of Laplace 2d equation

Tags: graphing-functions, laplacian

I have to plot distribution of 2D Laplace equation: $\Delta^2\psi\ (x,y)=0$

$\psi\ (x, 0) = \psi\ (x, 1) = \sin{x}$

$\psi\ (0, y) = \psi\ (1, y) = 0$

So I have these graphs:
[image: first]
[image: second]
[image: third]

Is there correct one?

Comment: Where did you get the graphs from? If you made them yourself, I suppose you would know which one came from the correct boundary value problem? In any case, none of three look right because they have different values on top and bottom.

Comment: I wrote a Python script, but I can't check it, so I'm asking for help here...

Comment: Hi. We lack information. Which of the axes are x and y? Which of the labels on the axes correspond to 0 and 1? The "boundary effects" on the left could as well be a sine function. This problem is too badly specified to be able to help with. What are the images even supposed to show, the final solution? The initial conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first two images, the boundary effects on the left look bad; they should not be there. The third image looks exactly right for the boundary value problem with $$\psi(x,0)=-\sin x,\quad \psi(x,1)=\sin x$$ $$\psi(0,y)=0=\psi(1,y)$$ Indeed, its graph shows **anti**-symmetry with respect to the horizontal line $y=1/2$: namely, $\psi(x,1-y)=-\psi(x,y)$. The boundary conditions you describe are **symmetric**: $\psi(x,1-y)=\psi(x,y)$. None of the plots have this symmetry.

So, my suggestion is: look for a sign error in the script that produced the third plot.